# Is this normal behavior for a unique index in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I'm working with SQLite in Flash.
I have this unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX songsIndex ON songs ( DiscID, Artist, Title )
```

I have a parametised recursive function set up to insert any new rows (single or multiple).

It works fine if I try to insert a row with the same DiscID, Artist and Title as an existing row - ie it ignores inserting the existing row, and tells me that 0 out of 1 records were updated - GOOD.

However, if, for example the DiscId is blank, but the artist and title are not, a new record is created when there is already one with a blank DiscId and the same artist and title - BAD.

I traced out the disc id prior to the insert, and Flash is telling me it's undefined. So I've coded it to set anything undefined to "" (an empty string) to make sure it's truly an empty string being inserted - but subsequent inserts still ignore the unique index and add a brand new row even though the same row exists.

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite allows `NULL`able fields to participate in `UNIQUE` indexes.  If you have such an index, and if you add records such that two of the three columns have identical values and the other column is NULL in both records, SQLite will allow that, matching the behavior you're seeing.

Therefore the most likely explanation is that despite your effort to `INSERT` zero-length strings, you're actually still `INSERT`ing `NULL`s.

Also, unless you've explicitly included `OR IGNORE` in your `INSERT` statements, the expected behavior of SQLite is to throw an error when you attempt to insert a duplicate `INDEX` value into a `UNIQUE INDEX`.  Since you're not seeing that behavior, I'm guessing that Flash provides some kind of wrapper around SQLite that's hiding the true behavior from you (and could also be translating empty strings to `NULL`).

Comment: Thanks Larry. That makes sense then. Also, I'd screwed up the code I made to replace anything undefined with "". I've changed it, and it's properly saving empty strings now. Thanks mate.

Comment: If I may offer a word of advice, don't store empty strings.  If the data is genuinely unknown, use NULL (and modify your indexing model if necessary).  Otherwise, create a special string value such as "No Disc" and use that.  It's hard to understand the difference in meaning between NULL and empty strings and bebugging the difference between NULL values and empty strings can difficult -- as I think you may already have discovered!

Answer (score 0):

Larry's answer is great. To anyone having the same problem here's the SQLite docs citation explaining that in this case all NULLs are treated as **different** values:

> For the purposes of unique indices, all NULL values are considered
> different from all other NULL values and are thus unique. This is one
> of the two possible interpretations of the SQL-92 standard (the
> language in the standard is ambiguous). The interpretation used by
> SQLite is the same and is the interpretation followed by PostgreSQL,
> MySQL, Firebird, and Oracle. Informix and Microsoft SQL Server follow
> the other interpretation of the standard, which is that all NULL
> values are equal to one another.

See here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html